How to determine the value of poolsize in redis client for go
I am using github.com/go-redis/redis/v8 package with the following configurtaion of client
rClient := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:      strAddr,
        Password:  "",
        DB:        db,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{},
    })

I am observing some latency in fetching values from redis. I checked the Amazon ElastiCache (Redis OSS) metrics and the command latency for get is in microseconds, However the latency in receiving the value to my application is much  higer (300ms to 6s).
I want to understand how can I determine the correct values of options like poolsize.
Also, here it is mentioned that .By default, the pool size is 10 connections per every available CPU as reported by runtime.GOMAXPROCS. In most cases, that is more than enough and tweaking it rarely helps. Can anyone help me in understanding why this is said as more than enough for most cases.
The redis metrics OSS also shows that avg current connections value is 4.5K in 5 minutes. How should I determine the poolsize and other configuration to reducy latency in receiving values.


avg current connections value is 4.5K in 5 minutes

This is extremely high number of connection. 
The reason 10 connection per CPU are more than enough is that Redis is single threaded, and unless you're working with a huge cluster or a huge replication group, more than lets says 80 connection wouldn't do any good.
If this is the amount of connection you see per 5 mins. Unless you have a lot of instances running your app (like really a lot), you probably have a problem with connectivity or logic in your app makes the client reconnect or fail and recreate. It is also possible that your whole app is going up and down. 
I don't think your issue is the pool size, try to debug your app behavior.
Feel free to share more details about the app, amount, and size of instances app running on, Elasticache details like amount of nodes and replicas, instance type, CPU and memory utilization, command types, and data size and code snippet. I'll try to give more insight.
For the follow-up questions:
When AWS offers 65k connections is because there are huge clients using huge clusters, using distributed system of tons of pods, so they end up with a big amount of connection. 
You have a small instance shared by three application, so there's no reason you have so many connections. 
That's mean that you have few thousands of idle objects doing nothing 99% percent of the time. 
You hurt your memory consumption, and probably hurt your network with too many clients trying to get the connection, and the biggest problem is that you are probably constantly create new connections, which of course hurt your performance. 
If I need to guess, you have some connections storm, can you share how many new connections you have per 5 min?
Update for second follow-up questions:
So you have 5 instances of your app, each running on 8 cores, let's be generous and say that all the 8 are available, and you get by default with the client 10 per CPU — we end up with 400 connections.
Didn't understand if the whole other three are connected to the same cache server, but let's say yes, you end up with 1200 all over all.
New connections should be on 0, unless something happens, if you have 3, ok, acceptable. 
If you have an average of 35, and spikes of 400 it's a proof of what I said — for some reason you keep creating new connections non-stop, meaning something wrong is happening. 
If those numbers are cumulating, that's means that you don't recreate on a dead connection because of crash or something, there is something in your app logic that keep creating them. 
I'd like to help further, but I need to see some code.
Do you track logs from your app?
You have some metrics?

Thank you for your response.
When I talk about connections, I am talking about the CurrConnections metric provided by AWS. I want to understand more on why this is considered as  extremely high number of connections as AWS mentions the limit as 65K simultaneous connections can be supported. If you can provide any insight or point me to any reference on why 4.5k in 5 minutes might induce latency then it would really help.

The instance type of redis is cache.m4.large and it has single node. The memory and CPU utilization of redis seems fine. (below 30%). Also our redis is currently being shared by 3 applications/microservices as resource utilization of redis seemed to be within control. Most of the commands are StringBasedCmds and GetTypeCmds ranging from 10k-100k per minute for both cmds and average is 35k for 24 hrs duration.

Ill edit my answer with answers to your questions.

Per 5 minutes on average there are 35 new connections. Sometimes it spikes upto 400 for a minute or two

When I say 3 applications, multiple containers are deployed for each of them.
On average 5 containers are running for my application. specifically.
If we consider golang client for redis, the default number of connection pool is 10 per every available CPU as reported by runtime.GOMAXPROCS. This should mean 8105 = 400 connections from one application at an instant , right ?

Again, updating my comment.

It's my work actually, I'm from elasticache, and on top of that I'm working on a multilingual ValKey/Redis-OSS client — ValKey-Glide (Go is under development, but we have stable Java, Python, and Node if you want to try :P ), so I have a good understanding of the topic :) I'd like to further help, but I need to see code, metrics, logs etc., or your db ID. If there's something you can share here it's great, otherwise if you can give a way to contact, or you can find me on the GitHub repo, find my contacts and reach out.

Thanks Avi, Really appreciate all the help. ! I reached out to you via email.
